# Searching a CAN-Bus Framework for Android or Java

Tags: java, android, frameworks, can-bus

I'm searching for an CAN-Bus Framework that can generarte me the complete frame format, by giving it my data. I need this for an android app. The connection to the CAN-Bus and the entire collision detection and so on is already established.

BR

Answer (score 1):

I am developing at the moment with the IXXAT CANblue II device. Nexus 7 -> Bluetooth -> CANblue II -> CANbus -> Control Unit.

They have on there Website an Android Development Kit with API maybe you can look through their code, and maybe this helps you.

Beside the fact that it uses Bluetooth to communicate with android, I can read in your topic that you only want to know how to communicate.

Just an idea :)

The API of IXXAT works excellent with android :)

Comment: Hi Fraggles, 
thanks for your response. I will take a look into it, it’s always nice to see some different approaches and the ADK looks at first sight excactly what I was looking for.
Yes, for me it was important to just put somewhere my CAN-messages and get the ready to be sent byte set. 
BR